# Combination of android:ellipsize and android:maxLines doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have a TextView which should display a maximum of 2 lines of text and the rest should be ellipsized(if that's the right term)

Here's what I'm doing

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="2"
android:singleLine="false"
```

But the text isn't getting cut off at the end as expected.

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/note_priority"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/note_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/note_priority"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="TitleTitleTitleTitleTitleTitleTitleTitleTitleTitle"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/note_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/note_title"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="DescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescription" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

EDIT: I have already tried using end and marquee both as the value for `android:ellipsize`

Comment: In your xml, you have ellipsize set to marquee. Change it to end.
Like this,
android:ellipsize="end"

Comment: In your code, unused ***android:ellipsize="end"*** ... haha..

Comment: @AbdullahRiaz, I tried that already, but it doesn't work

Comment: @Genesis, I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce it with your code.

Is this not the behavior you want?

From what I understand, it seems like the results you want and the results I tested.

And, singleLine is not necessary because the default value is false.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/note_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="DescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescaefawfeawfewafewaefawefasefsaefriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescription" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

> Preview

[image: Preview]

Comment: And, singleLine is deprecated.

Comment: No idea why this doesn't get shown as the pic you posted in my design preview. However, it does work when I run the app. So thank you.